# How to get unique values from a column access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table , contains more than 23,000 records. I want to get unique **BNO** values.

My table

```
  BNO          EID      E Description       CSCII
   678          7        power disc            011
   544          6        ekac                  067
   678          8        disc mag              011
   678          8        disc mag              011
   599          2        push button           978
   123          7        file dis              767
   123          5        file sep              768
```

To get Unique **BNO's** and also retrive all columns,how do i specify in a sql query. No BNO should contain duplicates.

Comment: ...and what should be - for example - the EID for the single row with  BNO=678?

Comment: If no BNO contains duplicates then why not just `SELECT *`? Otherwise if you want distinct values across columns: `SELECT DISTINCT BNO, EID, [E Description], CSCII`. If BNO does contain duplicates, then refer to the comment above... what should be the secondary criteria for which record of a particular BNO would display?

Comment: If BNO = 123, which values do you want for the other columns?  Should EID be 7 or 5?  CSII is 767 or 768?  Depending on your answers, I can write the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `BNO` to be unique and really don't care which of the possible values you want from the other columns as long as it's one of the ones existing for that `BNO`, you can just use `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT BNO, MAX(EID) EID, MAX(E_Description) E_Description, MAX(CSCII) CSCII
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY BNO
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot alias with an existing column name in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou you can if you write it like this `SELECT BNO, MAX(MyTable.EID) as [EID], MAX(MyTable.E_Description) as [E_Description], MAX(MyTable.CSCII) as [CSCII]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY BNO`

Comment: @Remou :) these things happen from time to time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY Column
```

Comment: "I want to get Unique BNO's _and also retrive all columns_"

Comment: Error Cannot group on fields selected with *